# SQL query to find the sum of fields in a column if a condition matches else return a default value

Tags: sql

I need a SQL query for the below scenario

```
House| SquareFoot| Color
```

---

```
House1  10        White
House2  20        White
```

The query should give a sum of SquareFoot(30) only if all the values in Color field are the same. Else it should return (0) for the below scenario

```
House| SquareFoot| Color
```

---

```
House1  10        White
House2  20        Red
```

Please let me know the best way this can be achieved through SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN MIN(Color) = MAX(Color)
             THEN SUM(SquareFoot)
             ELSE 0
        END) as return_value
FROM t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here first we will check from count whether distinct value is = 1 then total will be sum(SquareFoot)
Or if count of distinct will not be = 1 then total will be 0

```
select iif((select COUNT(distinct(Color)) from tblName) = 1, sum(SquareFoot), 0) as Total from tblName
```